# Search Button - Validate textbox before button run

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to run a javascript function in my index.cshtml to clean some textboxes of possible unwanted characters and aditional spaces.

The site runs on .NET CORE MVC.

Button Code:

```
<button onclick="executeValidationTest()" class="btn btn-success ladda-button ladda-button-infinite" data-style="expand-right" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Recherche</button>
```

The problem is... the search starts without running my cleaning script first.
As a result i get my search result with some characteres that i dont want in the default search.

I tried with another button and it works fine but users hate to click multiple buttons.

I noticed there is a code that includes a script:

```
@Html.AddResource(PageResourceType.Javascript, @<script>SomeScriptAlreadyInTheFile</script<)
```

I tried to put my code in here but it doesnt work either.

My Script:

```js
   function executerTestDeValidation() {
      console.log("Script call ok");

     
      if (document.getElementById("ISBN").value != "") {
         
         var string = document.getElementById("ISBN").value;

         // OUTPUT
         console.log("Before Clean: " + string);

         // ___________________________________
         // START CLEAN - Use string variable

         // Clear all non numbers
         string = string.replace(/\D/g, "");
         console.log("After Clean: " + string);

         // Check char total numbers
         var n = string.length;
         console.log("Lenght: " + n);

         // Check if full string is multiple of 13 - rest zero
         var rest = n / 13;
         if (n % 13 != 0) {

            // IF DIVISION BY ZERO = ERROR
            // console.log("Lenght: " + n + " is NOK");
            document.getElementById("txtBox").value = "ERROR";

         } else {
            // IF DIVISION BY ZERO = GOOD
            // console.log("Lenght: " + n + " is Good (Divisible par 13 et reste 0)");
            // Add spaces every 13 Chars
            var chuncks = string.match(/.{1,13}/g);
            var string = chuncks.join(" ");
            // console.log("After space split: " + string);
            document.getElementById("ISBN").value = string;

            // Check for last digit verification number on each ISBN number
            // ...
         }
      }
   }
```

Where do i put my script call so that my script is run when the button is pressed before the default search is executed?

Best regards
Rui

Comment: show the javascript

Comment: make use of sections, place it under the script tag

Comment: I have added my full script, not sure it is necessary, i just need to know where do i put my call for the script to run before the default search, when the button is pressed.

Comment: will this section make my script run before the default search function in my button? My button have no code so i suspect the call is made from another "listener" that gathers all text fields and lunches the search to the database. I need to fint that call and put mine first and make sure mine terminates before the other.

Comment: Assuming this HTML is within a `<form>`, then the problem isn't where you put your code, it's that your button is a `type="submit"` and this will submit the form automatically regardless of any JavaScript event set on the button - unless you use JavaScript to suppress this behaviour, and then only submit the form manually using script once you're happy it's valid. Google for "JS prevent default" to find out how. Or you could set `type="button"` on the button (and then still use JS to submit the form if validation passes) to make it not have a form submit behaviour by default.

Comment: P.S.  if you want to be certain that your search is valid then you must provide server-side validation as well, because JS can easily be turned off or altered by users who wish to try and bypass validation.

Comment: ADyson, i love your anwer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with onKeyUp(), but the user ADyson put me in the right direction for a truly functional solution.